# How do I return a result after a dialog closes?

Tags: android, xamarin.android

**How do I return a result after a dialog closes?**

I want to have a **function** launch a dialog and return the state of the dialog after it closes.

I was expecting a result to be returned after the dialog closes. However, this does not appear to be the case for Android.

**My code is below:**

```
public partial class NavigationListener
{
   public delegate Core.Entities.Filter RequestFilterHandler();
   public event RequestFilterHandler RequestFilter;
   ...
}
```

...

```
Core.Entities.Filter InitializeFilter() =>
    NavigationListener.Instance.RequestFilter += OnRequestFilter;

void OnRequestFilter()
{
    using (var alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this))
    {
        alert.SetView(LayoutInflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.Filter, null));
        var dialog = alert.Create();
        dialog.SetTitle("Filters");

        dialog.CancelEvent += (s, e) =>
            {
                var dateSubmitted = OnDateSubmittedFilterSet();
                var engagementFee = OnEngagementFeeFilterSet();

                _filter = new Core.Entities.Filter(dateSubmitted, engagementFee);
            };

        dialog.Show();
    }
}
```

Comment: Why don't you add listener to your dialog ? You will be notified when the user click on dialog button.

Comment: @Bipi I had already setup my test automation via TDD. I was hoping that I wouldn't have to alter my automated tests for this feature because of UI constraints.